# BBEdit GREP - To break line if there is no blank line above

Tags: regex, grep, bbedit

I am trying to organise a bunch of documents that has

" [ " brackets.

I have achieved to organise them to [ to come on as new line all the time
however I need them to have 1 line of blank space on top every time.
Conditionally if there is blank line already, no need to be done, just one line.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the input data and also what you want the output data to look like?

Comment: [12:34:56.78] I have managed to solve this by removing all blank lines and breaking every [\d. Would there be any elegant way to this? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I still don't believe I (or many others) understand your problem. But if you're OK to close it out then OK.